# shock wave jump conditions

Tags: optimization, scipy, physics

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

x1=input("P1")
y1=input("rho1")
v1=input("velocity1")


def eqn(x):                              #three jump condition equations

    f1=(x[1]*x[2])-(y1*v1)
    f2=x[0]+(0.5*(y1**2)*(v1**2)/x[1])-x1-(0.5*y1*v1*v1)
    f3=(0.5*(y1**2)*(v1**2)/(x[1]**2))+(2.5*(x[0]/x[1]))-(0.5*v1*v1)-(2.5*(x1/y1))

    return(f1,f2,f3)

y=[10,11,12]         #initial guess
print fsolve(eqn,y)
```

`I have to solve three non-linear system of equations also called the jump conditions in shock waves numerically. I have been asked to do so using scipy.optimize where we take three known parameters and use them to find the rest three parameters.
However I'm not getting the correct result and it varies heavily based on the initial guess value.

[Following are the relations. I am taking the value of P1, rho1 and V1 from the user and trying the find out the rest three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN27U.png)

Comment: Why do you use `x` 's and `y` 's instead of proper variable names? What is the input `y`? And what are `f1, f2, f3`?

Comment: sorry, but I am new to this site, however I've edited the question a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equations seem to be correct apart from a small Python-specific detail. The solution turns out to be very simple: convert all inputs to *floats*.

```
x1=float(input("P1"))
y1=float(input("rho1"))
v1=float(input("velocity1"))
```

The problem was that `x1/y1` in the expression for `f3` was evaluated with *integer division* (which truncates the result) instead of *floating-point division*.

This means you probably tested with integer values. Giving the original code float-format inputs (e.g. `5.0, 14.0, 3.0`) also worked as expected.